# Can't start Rails Server "sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)" on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, debian

I've created a new Rails project using rails new

When I try to start it with rails server I get the following output :

> root@debian:/home/marcel/workspaces/rails/sample# rails server
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in`rescue in '
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`each'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in`require'
>           from /home/marcel/workspaces/rails/sample/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in`require'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in`tap'
>           from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `'

I'm using

- ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
- Gem 1.8.25
- Rails 4.0.0

This is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you don't need the sqlite3-ruby gem.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed sqlite3-ruby but that doesn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't install libsqlite3-dev package on your debian.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```